# Amazon ECS API to return secure images URL

Tags: amazon-ecs

I'm using the API to get list of products with parameters:

```
'Keywords' => 'search,
'Operation' => 'ItemSearch',
'SearchIndex' => 'All',
'AssociateTag' => 'my-tag',
'AWSAccessKeyId' => 'my-key-id',
'ResponseGroup' => 'Medium',
'Service' => 'AWSECommerceService',
'Timestamp' => gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'),
'Version' => '2010-09-01',
```

I'm receiving images only from insecure server, e.g.

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/417YQ3xWx7L._SL75_.jpg
```

I have learned that this image is also available under the URL:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/417YQ3xWx7L._SL75_.jpg
```

Can I make API to return the secure URL in the response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see this is an old question. Probably still actual.

You can replace the result url with simple str_replace.

```
$image-url = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/417YQ3xWx7L._SL75_.jpg"

$new-image-url = str_replace('http://ecx.', 'https://images-na.ssl-', $image-url);
```

Comment: This is great, and I think it's safe to say Amazon won't be changing these https URLs soon since many other websites rely on them. Thank you!

Comment: This is awesome...for North America. We need a wiki of substitutions for the rest of the world! Anyone know?

Comment: Agreed this is good news. If user doesn't see green https symbol, they may not feel safe on website. They may not feel as though it's legitimate. Even though I may not be retrieving sensitive data, it still looks great to have the green symbol so thank you